# Erro na Integração Android Studio 2.3 com GitLab

Tags: android, git, gitlab

Estou aprendendo a versionar e seguindo um passo a passo no Stack OverFlow quase deu certo, porém ocorre um erro que não consigo corrigir.

Estou usando o terminal dentro do Android *Studio*

Segui todos os passos para carregar meu repositório local pra dentro do *GitLab*, como *First Commit*, porém ocorre a mensagem abaixo e nada é enviado...

```
git init
git remote add origin https://DharanaVentura@gitlab.com/DharanaVentura/XXXXXXX.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master  

Counting objects: 64, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 514.05 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Tente inserir na sua pergunta todo procedimento  que está realizando desde o `git add` .

Comment: Sim , farei agora. Grata.

Comment: o erro está nessa linha `error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053`. O commit que vc está enviando é muito grande/pesado?

Comment: Oi Ricardo, obrigada pela ajuda. Não é pesado não, só um app de teste mesmo.

Comment: @DharanaVentura, você está versionando apenas os arquivos de código ou também está versionando as bibliotecas do app?

Comment: Oi, eu estava versionando as bibliotecas também. Obrigada por responder Dherik. Abraços